# Hitting enter key in visual studio 2013 creates delete issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard

Can someone possibly shed light on an issue I'm having:

In Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, on occasion after hitting the enter key on my keyboard the previous character or 4-5 lines of characters are deleted. This occurs about every 2-3 enter key strokes and I cannot discern a pattern.

I switched keyboards and this is still occurring so it's not a keyboard issue (one keyboard was wired and another was wireless).

I tried typing the same lines in MS Word and there was no deletion issue.

So I believe this is a phenomenon only in VS 2013 but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I did to create this problem. As you can imagine it is quite annoying to have characters deleted every time I hit enter.

Does anyone recognize this problem and know what I have to do to resolve it? Or barring that, is there a way to do a reset (w/o reinstalling VS 2013) of key bindings?

**Update:**

I'm working on the same project on my laptop (same packages installed) and it works fine. The problem seems to be on my desktop. Also, I just created a new project on my desktop and the issue doesn't seem to occur in this project... so it's project specific.

Packages used in problem project:
Default mvc 5 packages,
Angular JS,
Angular JS Core,
ANTLrv3,
Bootstrap Datepicker,
Ckeditor-full,
Elasticsearch.Net,
EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact,
EntiyFramework,
jQuery,
Json.Net,
Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Core Libraries, Client Libraries, Web Host,
NEST,
Respond JS,
Selenium WebDriver Support Classes,
Selenium WebDriver,
WebGrease

All packages are up to date.

I'll try reinstalling the packages ...

Comment: Sounds really strange to me. Do you have Visual Studio plugins installed?

Comment: Good question.By plugins do you mean packages? I do have packages installed for the project.

Comment: Update: It is "fixed", as in I can no longer reproduce the problem.  However, I cannot pin point what fixed the problem. A few things occurred at the same time: 1) Computer was restarted, before you say that fixed it I already tried that as a fix twice before but it hadn't worked, 2) The packages were updated, 3) I started a new project to test if it was isolated to my current project. After doing all that, the problem is gone and no clue why.